# В IE7 фоновая картина не отображается на весь экран,в Хроме и Мозилле все норм

Tags: css

В IE7 фоновая картина не отображается

```css
 body{
 direction:rtl;
 
 margin-right:300px;
 margin-left:300px;
 margin-bottom:100px;


 background-position:center center;
 background-image:url("325.png");
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-attachment:fixed;
 background-size:100%;
 
}
```

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоваться, нахрена вам IE7?

Comment: IE8!!!ну конечно.прошу прощение за невнимательность...после 12 часов работы и не такое бывает.

Answer (score 1):

Задайте минимальную высоту и замените background-image на background `body { min-height: 265px; background: url("325.png") no-repeat 0 0 fixed;}` И все заработает.

Comment: 265? Откуда взята эта цифра?О_о

Comment: @MedvedevDev, видать хрустальный шар)))

Comment: С потолка ) можно 100vh но тогда нужно еще объяснять что такое вьюпорт

Comment: @RuslanSemenov, vh не подойдет, ибо ie7 не понимает

Comment: Да ребята, согласен с замечаниями, но и заодно напомнили background-image тоже не поддерживается в ie7, нужна замена на краткий background )